# Define limits of image

Tags: android-studio, bitmap, kotlin, imageview, touchscreen

I have an imageview and I draw circles when touch on the screen, for selected points. But I didn’t want put the circles outside the imageview limits. The image is a SVG with the contours of the human body. How can I define the limits of image?

Here is my code:

Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var layout: RelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout1)
    layout.addView(CustomView(this))

    var imageBody: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.body)

    var mBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)        
}

class CustomView(context: Context) : View(context) {       

    val brush = Paint()
    var coordX: Float = 0.0f
    var coordY: Float = 0.0f

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        var X = event!!.getX()
        var Y = event.getY()
        coordX = X
        coordY = Y
        invalidate()

        var text :String = "X: " + coordX + "\nY: " + coordY
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas)
            /*Circle Color*/
            brush.setARGB(255, 105, 103, 103)
            /*Circle*/
            canvas.drawCircle(coordX, coordY, 10f, brush)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simple Math. In your `onTouchEvent()` implementation query `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` and clamp the coordinates of your touch event according to the circle you want to draw.

Since your circle has a radius of `10f`, `coordX` is `Math.max(10f, Math.min(X, getMeasuredWidth() - 10f))` and `coordY` likewise `Math.max(10f, Math.min(X, getMeasuredHeight() - 10f))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't solve the issue. What I really need is for the event to not occur when the user clicks outside of my image (human body).

Comment: Then check for that (the reported touch will probably then be out of bounds of the View) and swallow / ignore the event in this case.